# Getting javascript value from an input tag

Tags: html, powershell, webrequest, powershell-4.0

Ignoring that this would be very simple to replicate locally I have taken a shine to using http://dinopass.com for giving people simple temporary passwords so as to get away from using "Welcome1" all the time.

When the above page loads you see nothing much other than a box that contains a  password. I want to extract that to use in my scripts.

In its simplest form I tried to do something like this:

```
$wr = Invoke-WebRequest www.dinopass.com
$wr.ParsedHtml.getElementById("password-input")
```

However there is no content for `.Value`, `.InnerText` or any other value from looking at `Get-Member`. I am assuming that the password is generated via JavaScript but I would also assume that it needs to be rendered somewhere in order to be viewed by my browser.

Looking at the HTML of the page I can see why I am having issues since there does not appear to be text to extract:

```html
<div id="password"><input id="password-input" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Where can I find where this value is stored programatically?

Comment: I would be more than happy if this was a dupe. Just having issues finding one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating the process by searching html elements...DinoPass also has an API available that you are welcome to use.

Have you tried using http://www.dinopass.com/password/simple or http://www.dinopass.com/password/strong ?

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://www.dinopass.com/password/simple
```

Using `irm` precludes having to deal with the object that gets returned by `iwr`.

Comment: I just figured this out, looking at the JS file and was going to edit my answer, but it's moot now. This is the way to go! And it lets you use `-UseBasicParsing`

Comment: @Matt Not exactly sure why you would need `-UseBasicParsing` but just testing it this way `$password = Invoke-RestMethod http://www.dinopass.com/password/simple` works beautifully for me.

Comment: @krousemw Agreed that it works without it just fine in this case.

Comment: I was originally writing it for use with `iwr` then realized `irm` is a better fit and left the extra switch. FWIW though, I'm on PS v5 and it works. My guess is that it gives raw JSON instead of deserializing in that case, which in this instance doesn't matter.